# Having trouble calling this class

Tags: java, class, printf

I just learned about how to create classes and how to use them with other classes to an extent. Anyway I'm trying to run what would seem like to many of you as an easy program but I can't see what I did wrong since there is no error in the code I write but probably in the syntax I made one.

```
class Noob {
    String name;
    int age;

}

public class App {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Noob kid1 = new Noob();
    kid1.name = "Andrew";
    kid1.age = 20;

    System.out.printf("Hello my name is %d and I'm %d years old", kid1.name, kid1.age );
}

}
```

Comment: Change the first %d to %s and it should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`%d` is a placeholder that expects an integer. Since `kid1.name` is a string, you need to use `%s`. Look [here](http://alvinalexander.com/programming/printf-format-cheat-sheet) for a list of format codes.